# The table top is in the shape of a regular heptagon and diagonals are drawn on it. In how many ways can the figure be colored with two colors?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, combinations

The table top is in the shape of a regular heptagon and diagonals are drawn on it as shown below:

[image]

In how many geometrically different ways can the resulting figure be colored with two colors at our disposal (while not having to use both), as each area into which the diagonals divided the polygon is painted with one color?

---

My solution:

Therefore our group of rotations consists of:

Axis of rotation $A$ (normal rotation "as a steering wheel") to the left ($=$ to the right):

[image]

- $1 \times$ axis $A$ rotated to the right by $\frac{360^{o}}{7}$ ($=$ to the left by $\frac{360^{o} \cdot 6}{7}$) gives one cycle with $22$ elements: $x_{22}$, constant points: 2 (all $22$ areas colored with the same color - we can choose one of two)
- $1 \times$ axis $A$ rotated to the right by $\frac{360^{o} \cdot 2}{7}$ ($=$ to the left by $\frac{360^{o} \cdot 5}{7}$) gives one cycle with $22$ elements: $x_{22}$, constant points: 2 (all $22$ areas colored with the same color - we can choose one of two)
- $1 \times$ axis $A$ rotated to the right by $\frac{360^{o} \cdot 3}{7}$ ($=$ to the left by $\frac{360^{o} \cdot 4}{7}$) gives one cycle with $22$ elements: $x_{22}$, constant points: 2 (all $22$ areas colored with the same color - we can choose one of two)
- $1 \times$ axis $A$ rotated to the right by $\frac{360^{o} \cdot 4}{7}$ ($=$ to the left by $\frac{360^{o} \cdot 3}{7}$) gives one cycle with $22$ elements: $x_{22}$, constant points: 2 (all $22$ areas colored with the same color - we can choose one of two)
- $1 \times$ axis $A$ rotated to the right by $\frac{360^{o} \cdot 5}{7}$ ($=$ to the left by $\frac{360^{o} \cdot 2}{7}$) gives one cycle with $22$ elements: $x_{22}$, constant points: 2 (all $22$ areas colored with the same color - we can choose one of two)
- $1 \times$ axis $A$ rotated to the right by $\frac{360^{o} \cdot 6}{7}$ ($=$ to the left by $\frac{360^{o} \cdot 1}{7}$) gives one cycle with $22$ elements: $x_{22}$, constant points: 2 (all $22$ areas colored with the same color - we can choose one of two)
- $1 \times$ axis $A$ rotated to the right by $\frac{360^{o} \cdot 7}{7} = 360^{o}$ ($=$ to the left by $360^{o}$) - identity gives $22$ cycles with $1$ element:  $x^{22}$, constant points: ${22}^2$ (all $22$ areas colored with any color - we can choose for each of them one of two)

I thought there would we second axis: axis of rotation $B$ (rotation "as a coin flip"):

[image]

But now, as I think about it - it can't be - because the only combinations of flips that don't change the general "shape" of the regular hexagon are identities and those we have already counted. So I assume that those are all possible rotations that result in changes of our points (colorings).

Therefore I would say that, by Burnside's lemma, the number of different ways the areas described in the statement of the problem can be painted is equal to:

$$ \frac{1}{7} \left( 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2^{22} \right) = \frac{12 + 2^{22}}{7}$$

Is my solution correct or am I missing something? It feels a bit "too straightforward" and therefore I got that strange feeling that I did that one wrong (that some rotations are missing).

Comment: Do you mean a heptagon? A hexagon has six sides.

Comment: You are right, thank you for help. I've edited my post.

Comment: I don't see why you rule out "coin flips". Those are generally counted as symmetries of regular polygons. The regular heptagon has a group of $14$ symmetries, called the dihedral group.

Comment: @GerryMyerson He described it as a "table top". You can rotate a table, but you cannot always turn it upside down.

Comment: @Mike, OK, I forgot that when I read 'because the only combinations of flips that don't change the general "shape" of the regular hexagon are identities and those we have already counted' – no mention there of table tops, just of the shape of the polygon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have made a mistake. When counting colorings that are unchanged after rotation by $1/7$ of a full turn, it is not true that *all* 22 regions need to be the same color. Regions come in four distinct shapes: 7 large triangles, 7 quadrilaterals, 7 small triangles, and 1 central heptagon. The only constraint is that similarly shaped regions must be the same color. This means there are $2^4$ ways to choose a coloring which is invariant under a $1/7$ turn; for each of the 4 types of region, there are two choices of coloring.

The same mistake applies to your calculations for $2/7$, $3/7$, ... , $6/7$ turn. Therefore, the correct answer is
$$
\frac{6\cdot 2^4+2^{22}}{7}.
$$

Comment: You are right. Thank you!